# Создание JSON из из списка

Tags: python, json, zabbix

Всем привет, есть скрипт который подключается к сетевому оборудованию через Netmiko и получает список ACL, потом через findall ищется два параметра - это имя ACL и значение hitcnt, на выходе получается список: ['access-list out line 1 extended permit icmp any any', '0', и т.д.]

Мне нужно преобразовать этот список в JSON:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "{#ACLNAME}": "access-list out line 1 extended permit icmp any any"
  "{#HITCNT}": "0"
},
{
  и т.д.
}
]
}
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

[json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
import json

jsn = {"data": [
    {"{#ACLNAME}": "access-list out line 1 extended permit icmp any any",
     "{#HITCNT}": "0"
     }, ]
}
with open("jsn.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(jsn, f)
```

Comment: А где цикл? Я же говорю, есть список, то, что я скинул, это лишь небольшая часть.

Comment: @АртемЧернышев, а зачем тут цикл? Просто готовый объект передавайте в функцию json.dump

Comment: @insolor это я знаю, но вот как сформировать объект?

Comment: Как обычный словарь/список.

Comment: @insolor я это делал, но ещё раз говорю, объект, который я обозначил в первом посте я не могу сформировать.

Comment: Тогда у вас вопрос не про json вообще, а про преобразование данных (одного вида списка в другой вид). Стоит отредактировать вопрос с акцентом на это (а не на json), плюс желательно добавить больший пример входных данных.